# How does Mental Stress work for non-combat Veils?

Tags: dresden-files

If a Wizard casts a spell creating a Veil<sub>1 & 2</sub> they take a Mental Stress. According to the book Mental Stress goes away right after combat<sub>3</sub>, unless of course going from one conflict immediately into another. So obviously, when performing a Veil during a combat scene the Mental Stress will stay until the conflict is over. However, Veils done outside of combat can just hang around until the Wizard drops them or they're pierced<sub>4</sub> (or a new dawn), so the question becomes how long does the Mental Stress for non-combat Veils stick around? Does it go away almost immediately? Or does the Mental Stress box used stay checked off until the Veil is removed in one way or another?

- <sup>1</sup> YS pg 255, Spirit, paragraph 2
- <sup>2</sup> YS pg 276, Veils
- <sup>3</sup> YS pg 220, Recovering From Conflicts
- <sup>4</sup> YS pg 255, 2nd Sidebar Blurb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends primarily on what type of veil is begin used.

Thaumaturgy - The Mental Stress for a long term ritual veil will go away at the end of the scene in which it is cast. The power is released at that point and there is no reason for the wizard to be still stressed since the ritual is on automatic.

Evocation - This is probably the more common of the two types. Since this veil requires concentration to maintain we can consider the veil being released one of the requirements to recover the mental stress. The other requirement would be that the current scene ends.

Example: 
Molly and Murphy are trying to take a look around a warehouse without attracting undue attention so Molly puts up a really impressive veil and takes a 4 point mental stress hit. She doesn't have to pay any more so long as the scene lasts since she is concentrating on maintaining it.

Because this is a Dresden Files game though, something goes wrong. They walk into view of an IR camera and the veil isn't attuned for that. Molly and Murphy are spotted by the goons in the warehouse and confronted.

Now comes the part where you have to make a GM ruling on if the stress continues into the next scene. If they get into a verbal argument before guns come out (and I'm assuming they will) then maybe that's enough time to recover the mental strain after dropping the veil. It they go right to guns though I would argue that loosing the veil was the first thing that happened in the new conflict scene and that mental stress has already been taken.